# Contact is only deleted after refreshing the page

Tags: .net, angular

I am facing a problem regarding the deletion of a contact. I would like after I click on delete, to automatically delete the contact, not after refreshing.
This is my code:

**service :**

```
deleteContact(id:string): Observable<Contact> {
    return this.http.delete<Contact>(this.baseApiUrl + '/contacts/' + id);
  }
```

**component.ts:**

```
   deleteContact(id:string) {
      this.contactService.deleteContact(id)
      .subscribe({
        next: (response) => {
          this.router.navigate(['contacts']);
        }
      })
  }
```

**view:**

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary"(click)="deleteContact(contact.id)" data-bs-dismiss="modal">Yes</button>
```

Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: What's the code on your backend? Does it automatically returns _before_ deleting the record ?

Comment: I would suggest  that you should to invoke 'read' api to get the latest list of record after successful deletion and update your view accordingly. Let me know if this will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you make a request to delete the contact on server side. so pay attention that, the client side is not aware of it.
you can do one of this options:

1. when making an HTTP request to delete the contact, make it return the updated list of contacts so that you can update your local list.
2. in case you'r not controlling the server side, you can also make another http request to get the new list right after the deletion. something like

   `return this.http.delete<Contact>(this.baseApiUrl + '/contacts/' + id).pipe(switchMap(() => this.http.get<Contact>(this.baseApiUrl + '/contacts/'));`

hope it helps :)